# HTML5 canvas - moving circle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote the following html code on my text editor:

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var canvasC = document.getElementById("canvasCircle");
  var contextC = canvasC.getContext("2d");
  var canvasBG = document.getElementById("canvasBackground");
  var contextBG = canvasBG.getContext("2d");

  var xPos = 50;
  var yPos = canvasC.height / 2;
  var radius = 40;
  var endXPos = canvasC.width - 75;
  var change = 10;
  var startAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 0;
  var interval = 80;
  var endAngle = (Math.PI / 180) * 360;

  contextBG.fillStyle = "silver";
  contextBG.fillRect(0, 0, canvasBG.width, canvasBG.height);

  var intervalID = setInterval

  function drawCircle() {

    contextC.clearRect(0, 0, canvasC.width, canvasC.height);

    contextC.strokeStyle = "green";
    contextC.lineWidth = 4;
    contextC.shadowOffsetX = 3;
    contextC.shadowOffsetY = 3;
    contextC.shadowBlur = 5;
    contextC.shadowColor = "grey";

    xPos += change;

    if (xPos > endXPos) {
      clearInterval(intervalID)
    };

    contextC.beginPath();
    contextC.arc(xPos, yPos, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
    contextC.stroke();
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="canvasCircle" width="400" height="125" style="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; left:auto; top:auto; z-index: 2">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
  <canvas id="canvasBackground" width="400" height="125" style="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; left:auto; top:auto; z-index: 1">
    Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
</div>
```

The code I draw was supposed  to show a circle moving from left to right, but for some reason, only the background remains.
 Can someone please tell me what I did wrong, please and thank you.

Comment: You never invoke the drawCircle() function? And why do you have multiple of canvas elements, isn't the goal to draw them on the same canvas? you also have some interval variable that you never use...surely there is some code missing?

Answer (score 1):

After define your function `drawCircle()` you forgot to call it and for moving your circle you have to use `setInterval` for calling this function contentiously

Add `setInterval(drawCircle, 1000);` after `function drawCircle() {...}` in your script.